# require minimum length of a variable in a django url

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

This bit from my urls.py requires a nine character value...

```
(r'^launch/(?P<app_id>[0-9A-Za-z]{9})/*', 'mysite.views.launch_app'),
```

How do I change this so it requires a *minimum* nine character value?

Answer (score 4):

Changing the RegEx to`{9,}` should do it.

```
(r'^launch/(?P<app_id>[0-9A-Za-z]{9,})/*', 'mysite.views.launch_app'),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do: `[0-9A-Za-z]{9,}`  to match 9 or more.